# Relative layout constraints

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I was trying to create layout but don't understand how to put one view under another.
Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_to_continue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Scroll to continue with content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/scroll_to_continue">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Tap to Learn More"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And I want to put LinearLayout right ABOVE TextView with id scroll_to_continue. Can somebody help me with that?

P.S. `android:layout_above="@id/scroll_to_continue"` doesn't work as expected as well as `addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, scrollToContinue.getId());`

Comment: `android:layout_above="@id/scroll_to_continue"` for `LinearLayout` is correct but what about `TextView` *(with id scroll_to_continue)*? You've not provided any constraint to it.

Comment: You were right - need to constraint it first! android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have provide `TextView`'s position in the layout. I have set it to bottom using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. Then it's work. Check below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_to_continue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Scroll to continue with content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/scroll_to_continue">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Tap to Learn More"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_to_continue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Scroll to continue with content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Tap to Learn More"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```